# Percentage computation and Auto-Comma combination

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem. My percentage computation has a problem when I combined it into auto-comma function. If I insert a number for example 100,000 and the percentage is 10 %, the computation of my percentage is the first hundred of the data that I inputted. So the computation is 110 only I don't how to use the combination of that function. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Percentage computation code:

```
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#submitme').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var mytxt1 = [];
            var mytxt2 = [];
            var mytxt3 = [];
                $(".expense_name").each(function () {
                    mytxt1.push($(this).val());
                });             
                $(".expense_desc").each(function () {
                    mytxt2.push($(this).val());
                });     
                $(".expense_cost").each(function () {
                    mytxt3.push($(this).val());
                });     

                var perfTimes = $(this).serialize();
                $.post("addfunction.php", {results: perfTimes, txt1: mytxt1,  txt2: mytxt2,  txt3: mytxt3 }, function (data) {

if (data.errors) {
    var alertErrors = "The following errors were found: ";
    $.each(data.errors, function(index, error){
       alertErrors += "\n" + "\n" + error.message;//Add each error in a new line 

    });
    alert(alertErrors);
} 
else {
    alert(data.message);
    window.location.href = data.redirect;
            }
       }, "json");
            });
        });
</script>
<script>
    var nitem =0; 
    var ntotal = 0;

        function totalItemExpence(){
            ntotal = 0;
                $('.expense_cost').each(function(){ 
                    if($(this).val() != ""){
                        ntotal += parseFloat($(this).val()); 
                        }
                    }); 
                //$('#total').val(ntotal); 
            }
        $(document).on('change keyup paste', '.expense_cost', function() { 
            totalItemExpence();
            mytotal();
            }); 

        $('.btn').click(function() { 
            nitem++; 
                $('#wrapper').append('<div id="div' + nitem + '" class="inputwrap">' +
                    '<input class="expense_name" placeholder="Expense Name" id="' + nitem + '" required/>' +
                    '<input class="expense_desc" placeholder="Expense Description" id="' + nitem + '" required/>' +
                    '<input class="expense_cost" placeholder="Expense Cost" id="' + nitem + '" required/> ' +
                    '<br><br></div>');  
                }); 

        $('.btn2').click(function() {           
            ntotal = $('#total').val(); 
                $("#div" + nitem + " .expense_cost").each(function(){               
                    if($(this).val() != ""){
                        ntotal -= parseFloat($(this).val()); 
                        }
                    }); 

                    $("#div" + nitem ).remove();
                        nitem--; 
                    $('#total').val(ntotal); }); 




        var textbox = $("#txtTaxPercent");
        var ResultTextbox = $("#txtfctTaxValue");
        var PriceTextbox = $("#txtPurePrice");
        var pricetotal = $("#total");
        var pasamame = $(".expense_cost");

            $([PriceTextbox[0]]).bind("change keyup paste", function(e) {
                totalItemExpence();
                mytotal();
            });  

            $([textbox[0]]).bind("change keyup paste", function(e) {
                mytotal();  
            });  

            function mytotal()
            {
                $("#txtfctTaxValue").val(0);
                var Result;
                if(PriceTextbox.val()!=="" ){
                    Result1 = (parseInt(PriceTextbox.val())) * parseFloat(textbox.val() / 100);
                    Result = (parseInt(PriceTextbox.val())) * parseFloat(textbox.val() / 100) + (parseInt(PriceTextbox.val()));

                }

                else{
                    Result = 0;
                }
                Result = parseFloat( Result) + ntotal;
                pricetotal.val(Result);
                ResultTextbox.val(Result1); 

            }
```

Auto Comma code:

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $('input.number').keyup(function(event){
             // skip for arrow keys
             if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
                 event.preventDefault();
             }
             var $this = $(this);
             var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "").split("").reverse().join("");

             var num2 = RemoveRougeChar(num.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1,").split("").reverse().join(""));

             console.log(num2);


             // the following line has been simplified. Revision history contains original.
             $this.val(num2);
         });
       });

       function RemoveRougeChar(convertString){


           if(convertString.substring(0,1) == ","){

               return convertString.substring(1, convertString.length)            

           }
           return convertString;

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt()` does its best to create an integer.  If you have a non-numeric value (the comma) it stops there.  You need to strip out the commas before calling parseInt()

Do something like this, using replace on the string to get rid of unwanted chars.

```
if(PriceTextbox.val()!=="" ){
    var price = parseInt(PriceTextbox.val().replace(',','').replace('.',''));
    Result1 =price * parseFloat(price / 100);
    Result = price * parseFloat(price / 100) + (price);

}
```

If you want just the dollar portion, eliminate the second replace call (which is removing the decimal point).  That way 10,000.00 will be 10000 and not 1000000.

```
  var price = parseInt(PriceTextbox.val().replace(',',''));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CvnhV/

Comment: how do I code it sir. Sorry sir I don't know how to use AJAX very well.

Comment: The comma replaces 0 sir? If I input 1,000 the output is 10000.

Comment: Are you adding a decimal point?  You may want to remove the second replace so that decimal points remain and force the int to be whole numbers (dollars) and ignore cents.